# Getting Polygon shapearea

Tags: arcpy, geometry, area

i have 2 layers. layer1 and layer2. Both are polygons. I want to get both layers Shape_Area. I know I can get there shapeareas by using a searchcursor and extracting them, which I have done already.

I want to know if there is a quicker, shorter way to get a layers `shapearea` than using two separate search cursors?

My long way:

```
areas = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer1, "Shape_Area") as cursor:
    for x in cursor:
        areas['layer1'] = x
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer2, "Shape_Area") as cursor2:
    for y in cursor2:
        areas['layer2'] = y
```

I know there is `arcpy.Polygon.getArea()` but I am unsure how to use it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create cursors for every layer you work with. However, there is a token which you can use to get the area of polygons, using [SHAPE@AREA](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/):

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,'SHAPE@AREA',
                           spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(3338)) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        print row[0]
```

If you want to get areas of all polygons in a layer, you could also use list comprehension:

```
areas = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,'SHAPE@AREA',
                           spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(3338))]
```

Specifying the `spatial_reference` will let you retrieve the area in the units of this coordinate system (handy if your data is stored in decimal degrees but you want to get square meters).

If you want to iterate multiple layers in one shot, you could do this also with list comprehension:

```
layers = ['layer1','layer2']        
print [row[0] for layer in layers for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer,'SHAPE@AREA',spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(3338))]
```

Comment: do I need to specify the SR? does specifying the SR give me the shape area in the units of the SR?..

Comment: Yes, `specifying the SR give me the shape area in the units of the SR`

Comment: @ziggy, I have also added a snippet for getting all areas of all polys in multiple layers, since it seems you want to append everything to the variable `areas`.

Comment: An equal area projection would make more sense though.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall, good point. Ziggy, you can search for the equal area projections for your area: http://spatialreference.org/ref/?page=4&search=equal+area

Comment: ...I'm a little horrified to see Web Mercator being used as the spatial ref for an area calculation, even if it is an example. =/

Comment: @jpmc26, I won't let you down :) changed to Alaska Albers Equal Area :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking the best way to respond here is to address 2 minor points. First, in my opinion the *long way* approach you've constructed here is indeed an acceptable and worthwhile way to collect feature `Shape_Area` values from a feature class. Second, I'm seeing some small issues with your code. Most importantly, each `row` object you are iterating through in these `for` loops is over-writing the previous `row` object's `Shape_Area` for the `'layer1'` and `'layer2`' elements in your `areas` dictionary.

If the goal is to obtain a dictionary object reflecting each individual feature's `Shape_Area` tagged with the name of its parent feature class, then the code may look something like:

```
import arcpy

areas = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer1, ["OID@", "SHAPE@AREA"]) as cursor1:
    for row in cursor1:
        areas[layer1 + '_' + str(row[0])] = row[1]
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer2, ["OID@", "SHAPE@AREA"]) as cursor2:
    for row in cursor2:
        areas[layer2 + '_' + str(row[0])] = row[1]
```

Comment: Jim, i did not specify but i am batch automating many maps with these layers so I do want to overwrite the shape_area each time

Comment: but this is good approach nonetheless thanks

Comment: @ziggy all good thanks - best luck with this process.